# Entertaining video lectures of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[this calculus lecture on coursera.com](https://class.coursera.org/calc1-001/lecture/index) develops my interest in mathematics. I was very scared of math but after taking lectures of this course I just fall in love with math. I Now have Differential Equation subject in my study program and I was looking for some interesting lectures on differential equations similar to above calculus lectures. I have gone through the lectures available over internet even of [MIT course](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/Syllabus/) but they all are almost similar like boring black board teaching style explaining and solving problems. I am programing student and I found my self better understanding math by real time problems. not like x+y=something etc. Please if any one have something similar lectures available, share it please.

Note: I have searched this stachexchange before asking the question and yes I have found lectures links but as I mentioned earlier they are almost boring style teachings